# install ubuntu on MSI u100?

Tags: installation, 13.04

I have a MSI u100 and i have Ubuntu 10.04 and I don't like it. I don't have internet access at home. I downloaded 13.04 and tried to boot it from there and i did the start up disk creator but it still doesn't work. can anybody help?

Comment: You should at least provide us some idea of what you mean by "it still doesn't work."  What actually happens?

Comment: when i boot it from the usb it says missing OS

Comment: i think i might know whats wrong. i just plugged my usb into a different computer and i think i might need to install from the file in my documents

Comment: I would recommend AGAINST installing 13.04 (which is not a final release) without any sort of Internet connectivity to receive regular updates.  It is still in beta testing.  12.04 would be more reliable for you, I think.  Additionally, please go through the installation instructions for how to do a USB bootable ISO: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install (your computer requires you to hit 'DEL' to enter the BIOS if you need to define the boot device as the USB stick instead).  More detailed here: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/index.html

Answer (score 2):

In reply to Gravity, 13.04 is no longer in beta, release was last month.  In answer to your question it does sound like the USB stick wasn't created properly.

This link (same one as provided by Gravity) has much of the information you need on how to create those disks, whether it's USB stick or optical media.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install

When booting the netbook up I believe F11 brings up the boot menu.  Be sure you select the USB stick to boot from.